# How would law enforcement react to a "Jane Doe"?

Tags: creative-writing

In my story there's this woman who has a seizure/stroke/something-capable-of-putting-someone-into-a-coma while driving and gets involved in a car crash. The other driver suffered but a small concussion and material damage. Her seizure, however, causes her to go into a coma.

She carries no identity, her prints match no police database whatsoever and her car has all registers completely scraped.

She wakes up from her coma about 1 month later with little recollection of who she is and/or why she's there - she can remember only bits and pieces.

**How would law enforcement approach this person?**

She would be questioned, sure. But would she be detained? Is it possible that she's accused of something? Can the police actually hold her for a long period of time or they'll just have to let her go after a few days getting nothing from her?

Comment: This is a **plot** question, and thus inappropriate. Besides which in no two cases is the approach going to be quite the same.

Comment: Those questions are also not answerable by us. Because we are not writing your story.

Comment: This question just might be on topic on [law.se], as being about [Legal process and procedure](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Flag it for moderator attention if you'd like it migrated; bear in mind, I'm not a regular on that site, so my interpretation of their scope *may* be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If I were writing this situation, my police would know that unless they charge the amnesiac character that they cannot hold them in custody indefinitely - assuming US location. They would likewise require probable cause for any arrest which they would have to seek in the testimony of the other driver and any possible witnesses. Your character sounds shady in that their vehicle has been stripped of all VIN numbers. She might regain consciousness with a police guard and find she is under arrest - depending on your plot.

Your MC has a different problem, though, in that seizures themselves would not cause a coma. A seizure is a brief disturbance caused by extreme electrical activity in the brain that triggers multiple simultaneous responses. Commonly, a person who is having a seizure would be moving without volition - anything from a slight twitch to an extremely noticeable convulsion. Such might last seconds or lapse into a series of seizures which must be broken by medical intervention.

Said lack of volition would be a defence as the police would require intent, which is not the case with involuntary movements.

Epilepsy does not cause comas or memory loss - memory of the actual seizure itself can be blurred, but in most cases the person so effected just shakes it off and carries on - probably calling their doctor to complain that this prescription was no better than the last one and let’s get it right this time.

Assuming your MC is not a criminal fleeing justice - might have borrowed the car from a shady character - the possible repercussions of this seizure induced accident is a loss of driving privileges due to ‘violating medical probation’.

You might want to find another cause for the coma - as an epileptic myself, I would wonder why the author chose epilepsy when the facts don’t fit. I realize that in extreme cases it can be quite a disability, but what you might want to try - if this MC must be epileptic and given the worst case scenario, brain surgery would have been performed severing the corpus collusum. With the two halves of the brain no longer communicating, that could lead to some intriguing situations.

I don’t mean to criticize, but this is something of which I have knowledge and rather than you hearing this from the associations after finishing the work and maybe publishing it, I thought it best to let you know.

Comment: First of all thanks for answering. Second, I didn't mean to sound so uninformed - I should have written the thing that is in my actual file, which is  "she had a seizure/stroke/something else capable of putting her in a coma". The means are irrelevant as long as she ends up in a coma. Also, her memory loss was not caused by the "seizure" itself.

Comment: This question was really what's kinda written there: "what would people in charge do if a Mary Doe crashed her car, got into a coma and woke up a month later with no memory of it?"

Comment: I would not worry too much about it as those who do know tend to either have that as a diagnosis or be in the medical profession. Medically induced coma might be easier, but she’d have to be hurt to justify that or it was an error on the part of the hospital